# Axios - fetching products

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have made an endpoint, that returns all products in JSON format. I am trying to display the data from each product, on my index.html page. But I dont seem to able to get to data correct using Axios, this is my first time using axios, so please bare with me.

The endpoint/route /api/products/getAllProducts returns the following JSON

```
{
"message": "Fetched products..",
"data": [
{
"Product_ID": "017c24f4-8bd6-4bfc-a93e-f6f5d2426f6f",
"Product_title": "PC",
"Product_desc": "PC",
"Product_price": 1000,
"Product_picture": null,
"Product_color": "Blue",
"Product_location": 2150,
"Product_category": "Clothes",
"Product_created": "2022-04-13T00:00:00.000Z"
},
{
"Product_ID": "1",
"Product_title": "fisk",
"Product_desc": "fisk med skind",
"Product_price": 100,
"Product_picture": null,
"Product_color": "grøn",
"Product_location": 2100,
"Product_category": "mad",
"Product_created": "2022-04-13T00:00:00.000Z"
}
]
}
```

My code so far returns following error

> TypeError: products.map is not a function
> at showProducts (index.js:9:34)

This is my code  - I understand that since I am not getting the data correct, I cant use .map property, but I cannot figure out, what I am missing to get the data correctly.

```
const productsDOM = document.querySelector(".productsDOM");

const showProducts = async () => {
  try {
    const { data: products } = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:3000/api/products/getAllProducts"
    );

    const allProducts = products.map((product) => {
        return `<h1>${Product_title}</h1>`
    })

    productsDOM.innerHTML = allProducts
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

showProducts();
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: could you show (log) your products response?

Comment: If I do console.log(products); it returns following `{message: 'Fetched products..', data: Array(6)}
data: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
message: "Fetched products.."
[[Prototype]]: Object`

Comment: then you have to map products.data

products.data.map ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios response the data (your object) in the data (axios response object) field. So the axios response look like:

```
data: {
  "message": "Fetched products..",
  "data":[... your products...]
 }
}
```

and cause you just destructuring the axios response object. You have to destructuring again.

https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema

Comment: Thank you! I have to work on my destructuring!